# getting [object Object] instead of actual object values on dynamically creating template + Angular4

Tags: angular

My Scenario:
I have a component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'child-table',  
  template: `<dynamic [html]="dynamicHtml"></dynamic>`
})
```

On ngoninit(), I am dynamically creating this template on basis of 'propertyType' field present in collection of 'propertyItems' object.
PropertyType can be Numeric/String/Boolean/List etc. Depending on propertyType, I am fetching the template and embedding it under child-table template.

```
public ngOnInit(): void {
  this.dynamicHtml=``;
  this.dynamicHtml = '<table>';
  for (let propertyItem of this.propertyItems) {
    this.dynamicHtml+= this.getPropertyTemplate(propertyItem);
  }
  this.dynamicHtml+='</table>';
}

public getPropertyTemplate(propertyItem):string{
  let propValTemplate:string = `<tr>`;
  propValTemplate+=this.getTemplateOfPropType(propertyItem);
  propValTemplate+=`</tr>`;
  return propValTemplate;
}

private getTemplateOfPropType(property):string{
  if(property.propertyType == "Numeric")
  {
      return `<numeric-editable-property numericEditablePropertyItem="${property.value}" childproperty="${property}"></numeric-editable-property>`;
  }
  else if(property.propertyType == "String")
  {
      return `<string-editable-property stringEditablePropertyItem="${property.value}" property="${property}"></string-editable-property>`;
  }
}
```

---

Template for numeric-editable-property tag:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'numeric-editable-property',
  styleUrls: ['./propertyTemplateStyling.css'],
  template: `<td><input type="text" value={{numericEditablePropertyItem}} [(ngModel)]="numericEditablePropertyItem" #textarea
(change)="onPropValChange($event, textarea.value, childproperty)"></td>`     

})

export class NumericEditablePropertyTemplateComponent{ 
  @Input() numericEditablePropertyItem;
  @Input() childproperty:switchcommon.IPropertyItem;
  constructor(private deviceMgmtService: DeviceManagementService) {}

  public onPropValChange(event: Event, selectedVal: string, property: switchcommon.IPropertyItem): void {
    const message: Message.PropertyUpdateMessage = new Message.PropertyUpdateMessage();

    property.value = selectedVal;
    this.deviceMgmtService.updateProperty(property);
  }
}
```

---

Issue I am facing:

Unable to pass property as object from func getTemplateOfPropType(), statement:
    return `<numeric-editable-property numericEditablePropertyItem="${property.value}" childproperty="${property}"></numeric-editable-property>`, 
to 'numeric-editable-property' tag template i.e on calling onPropValChange() fn, childproperty input field shows [object Object] instead of actual object values which I recieve in getTemplateOfPropType() function.

I am new to coding, it will be greatful if somebody can tell me why I am getting [object Object] instead of actual object values.

Answer (score 1):

hey you may be used as

> In Views used json pipe

```
{{yourObject | json }}
```

> In Model used json stringify

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(yourObject))
```

**Thanks**

Comment: I am doing this(JSON.stringify(yourObject)) inside my updateProperty(property) fn.  My issue is I am not getting 'property' as object while passing it as function argument in updateProperty(). Basically 'childproperty' Input field is not recieving object as value which is set from statement <numeric-editable-property numericEditablePropertyItem="${property.value}" childproperty="${property}"></numeric-editable-property>. This above tag shows property as object but not in numeric-editable-property tag.

Comment: please add any screenshot of your error or in which it returns [object object]

Comment: Please find the screenshots explaining the behavior: http://imageshack.com/a/img923/6575/TQrSPN.jpg http://imageshack.com/a/img924/3902/opnfvG.jpg

Comment: Is it happening because I am returning template as string ?

Comment: did you solve this? I'm having the same problem. [object object] instead of the string, and the value is a string

Comment: @yngrdyn I had the same issue and only had to use {{ myObejct | json }} and that did the trick!